# Why is the command element supported in IE9 but not in IE10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I like the idea of the `command` element, but it doesn't seem to be supported in any (?) browser, well except IE9. But not in IE10. I'm curious why, is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the `command` element isn't supported in any browser. Firefox 15-19 does support the `menu` tag http://caniuse.com/#search=command , but doesn't use the `command` element as the official HTML5 recommends http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/interactive-elements.html#the-menu-element

I am not seeing the `command` element supported in IE9. Did you see that somewhere? It isn't listed in the MSDN IE9 Guide for Developers document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh410106#_HTML5_Semantic_Elements

As for why it isn't implemented in browsers other than Firefox, I'm not sure why that is the case. Maybe browsers aren't quite ready to answer the `menu` element and the complexities of that and usability, accessibility, etc...

The good news is that you can use a Polyfill for `menu` and `command` by using the following library https://github.com/medialize/jQuery-contextMenu I've not used it myself, but it was listed on Modernizr's HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills wiki https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Hi Elijah!:) Thanks for the reply :) Marekd it as right answer, probably as close as we'll get to an answer on this one ;)
As far as I know the Command is listed in the html spec - but has not been implemented. I was curious if there were any specific problems with the implementation or they just didn't see a need for it anymore. The tag is mentions several places: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_command.asp
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/commands.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800594/what-exactly-is-the-html5-command-tag-and-what-is-the-browser-support

Comment: Iris, yep it is in the official specification, but it is strange why it hasn't been implemented at all in any browser that I am aware of. If I run across mention or implementation of it I'll try to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

As said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19606400/1331956, the `command` element has been removed in favor of `menuitem`. That's probably why it has been removed from IE.