# html specification and tags like <command>

Tags: javascript, css, html, w3c

While going through w3 specifications, I found < command > as a new tag in HTML5.
I then checked whatwg to confirm the same.

I then checked mdn where they mark this feature as obsolete:

> < command> "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Also, I couldn't find this element in caniuse.

So I have a few questions

1) How did mdn decide to mark this element obsolete, when its still present on w3 & whatwg as new element?

2) None of the browser support this tag, so what is the point of specifications by w3 & whatwg?

3) Being a front end developer should I care about these specification?

4) Should I consider mdn as ultimate reference for the all the html elements and stop referring to whatwg & w3c?

5) Do chrome & safari has similar open repository for the html elements they support?

Here's link reference for [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/command), [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/command.command.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the HTML5 <command> tag and what is the browser support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800594/what-exactly-is-the-html5-command-tag-and-what-is-the-browser-support)

Comment: Hi Satej, I checked that already but dint get answer to my queries

Comment: *"Do chrome & safari has similar open repository for the html elements they support?"* - MDN is not just about what Firefox supports, indeed MDN documents some things that Firefox does not (and never did) support. MDN also tries to give an indication of which (of the major) browsers support the features it documents.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: In which W3C spec did you find the `command` element?

Comment: I have give a link above of the same. mdn + w3c

Answer (score 0):

It was introduced in 2014 and is considered obsolete in 2016 because `<menuitem>` tag has been introduced in place of that.

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer. however can you please provide source of it and also help me with my other queries